# Whatsapp Business Api gives error when accessing their apis

Tags: docker, whatsapp

I am working on Whatsapp Business API. When i am trying to access the API, it shows me an error with

> "details": "Connection refused. Please check if wacore is running."

Any help to solve it.
[This is my Docker Whatsapp container running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4nQJ.png)

[This is Postman api post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILk3Y.png)

Comment: Please help us first by showing more code and what have you already tried to resolve this issue...

Comment: Check if wacore is running.

Comment: _“When i am trying to access the API”_ - explain how you do that, please. All the screenshot shows is you making a POST request to your own server. We have no idea what software/script you have running there.

Comment: I am running a docker container which is provided by Whatsapp Business. and then i post request to the post and it shows me that error. I am new to Whatsapp Business. so i am following Whatsapp Business docs.

Comment: @NiteshKumar Did you find any solution?

Comment: @NiteshKunar did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means your waweb is running but your wacore container is not running or you somehow restart the wacore container.

You could run

```
docker ps -a
```

To find out the wacore container 
And run

```
Docker logs containerid
```

to see the logs , if you could grab the logs I could see why wacore is down for you

shutdown and restart normally will help

```
docker-compose down 
 docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience setting up the servers on AWS, there are 2 things that cause this error message to be returned.

1. The current cloud formation template has a bug, maybe, that doesn't add the DB password to the environment variables for the container images. Adding it manually and re-deploying fixes the issue.
2. The phone number you will be using for the business account, added on WhatsApp manager, needs to be registered with your instance with WhatsApp servers.